# I am not getting chart image in Safari browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, safari, safari-extension

Chart is coming in all browser but ecept in safari
    I don't no why can any one know about . I tryed using ASP Chart controls . Chart is coming in all browser but except safari

[image: It's coming in all browser like this]
[image: But in Safari it's coming like this]

My code is

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Report_Status.aspx.cs" Inherits="Report_Status" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Width="500" Height="300">
             <Titles>
                <asp:Title Text="REPORT STATUS" Font="Trebuchet MS, 14pt, style=Bold" Alignment="TopLeft" ForeColor="#0072bc" ></asp:Title>
            </Titles>
            <Legends>
                    <asp:Legend Alignment="Center" LegendStyle="Column" Docking="Right" Font="Trebuchet MS, 10pt" Name="Incident Classification"  />
                </Legends>
            <Series>
                <asp:Series Name="Approved"></asp:Series>
                <asp:Series Name="Rejected"></asp:Series>
            </Series>
            <ChartAreas>
                <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
            </ChartAreas>
        </asp:Chart>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

in Code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class Report_Status : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string _connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["demoConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        DateTime dat = DateTime.Now;
        string month = dat.ToString("yy-MM-dd");

        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(_connStr);
        conn.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(IF(Status='A',1,NULL))'A',COUNT(IF(Status='D',1,NULL))'D', YEAR(Start_Date_Time) FROM sh_report WHERE YEAR(Start_Date_Time)<=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 10 YEAR) GROUP BY YEAR(Start_Date_Time)", conn);
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
        //Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
        Chart1.DataSource = ds;
        Chart1.Series["Approved"].XValueMember = "YEAR(Start_Date_Time)";
        Chart1.Series["Approved"].YValueMembers = "A";
        Chart1.Series["Rejected"].XValueMember = "YEAR(Start_Date_Time)";
        Chart1.Series["Rejected"].YValueMembers = "D";
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        Chart1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

My config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;dir=c:\TempImageFiles\;" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ChartImageHandler" />
      <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </handlers>
    <modules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="MySql.Data, Version=6.9.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D" />
        <add assembly="MySql.Web, Version=6.9.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <membership defaultProvider="MySQLMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <remove name="MySQLMembershipProvider" />
        <add name="MySQLMembershipProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Clear" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile defaultProvider="MySQLProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <remove name="MySQLProfileProvider" />
        <add name="MySQLProfileProvider" type="MySql.Web.Profile.MySQLProfileProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="MySQLRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <remove name="MySQLRoleProvider" />
        <add name="MySQLRoleProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <siteMap defaultProvider="MySqlSiteMapProvider">
      <providers>
        <remove name="MySqlSiteMapProvider" />
        <add name="MySqlSiteMapProvider" type="MySql.Web.SiteMap.MySqlSiteMapProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </siteMap>
    <webParts>
      <personalization defaultProvider="MySQLPersonalizationProvider">
        <providers>
          <remove name="MySQLPersonalizationProvider" />
          <add name="MySQLPersonalizationProvider" type="MySql.Web.Personalization.MySqlPersonalizationProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" applicationName="/" />
        </providers>
      </personalization>
    </webParts>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalMySqlServer" />
    <add name="demoConnectionString" connectionString="****;user id=****;Password=****;database=****;convertzerodatetime=True" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <elmah>
    <!--
        See http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/SecuringErrorLogPages for 
        more information on remote access and securing ELMAH.
    -->
    <security allowRemoteAccess="false" />
  </elmah>
  <location path="elmah.axd" inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
      </httpHandlers>
      <!-- 
        See http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/SecuringErrorLogPages for 
        more information on using ASP.NET authorization securing ELMAH.

      <authorization>
        <allow roles="admin" />
        <deny users="*" />  
      </authorization>
      -->
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="ELMAH" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you checked the console to see if you have any errors?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include some details of what you are doing? (i.e. enough code to replicate the issue)

Comment: while i am trying to save my image it's saving as a html file

Comment: also if i open in new window it's showing as a 404 error